# heap corruption detected | C++

Tags: c++, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I get this "`heap corruption detected`" message after running this code :

```
uli& uli::operator =(char* n)
{
    char* buffer = new char[strlen(n)];

    char* p;
    int op;
    int coef;

    strcpy(buffer, n);

    while(*buffer)
    {
        op = strlen(buffer) - 5;
        p = (op >= 0) ? op+buffer : buffer;
        coef = atoi(p);

        if(coef > 65535)
            coef = atoi(++p);

        push(head, coef);
        *p = '\0';
    }

    delete buffer;       //  <- heap corruption detected

    return *this;
}
```

This is how I call the method:

```
uli x;
x = "9876123";
```

What does "heap corruption detected" mean ?

Comment: Have you though of using an object to handle the memory. Maybe a std::string instead of a char*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Heap corruption" generally means you wrote into unallocated memory, damaging the data structures used to make the memory allocator work.

There may be more problems, but the first one I see is on this line:

```
strcpy(buffer, n);
```

This will write `strlen(n) + 1` bytes to `buffer`, but `buffer` is only `strlen(n)` bytes long (the extra byte is the terminating `\0`.) Writing that extra byte results in undefined behavior, and may well corrupt the heap.

Comment: Also, don't miss Ates Goral's comment. If you allocate with `new[]`, you *must* free with `delete[]`.